# File stream parsing with busboy and write directly into GridFs in express

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, gridfs, busboy

:) Hi!

I'm trying to figure out how to write uploading file directly into GridFs in express framework.

I wrote codes as below and the problem is that file event "file" is never emitted.

:(

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var Busboy = require('busboy');

router.get('/test', function(req, res){
 res.render('test-gridfs', {title: 'TESTING GRIDFS'});
})

router.post('/test', function(req, res){
 var busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
 var gfs = req.gfs;

 busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename);
  file.pipe(gfs.createWriteStream({
   filename: 'moon.jpg',
   content_type: 'image/jpg'
  }))
 });
 busboy.on('finish', function() {
  res.json({result: 'finish'});
 });
 req.pipe(busboy);
})
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What does `console.log(req.headers['content-type'])` show?

Comment: I mean if you put that in your `post()` route handler, what does it output?

Comment: @mscdex console.log(req.headers['content-type']) shows 'multipart/form-data; boundary=-----WebkitFormBoundaryTJDADFAF'

Comment: I got this figured out! It was stupid! I required the another module multiparty in app.js and it caused everything.